# PWA to open specific URL

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I've been using the PWA Nuxt Module and overall I'm happy with the result. However, I encounter a problem but since I'm quite new working with PWAs, I'm not even sure if what I want is possible.

Right now, my app is showing properly if a user "Add to Home Screen" from their devices. My question is: Is possible to download the app from a specific URL and the PWA opens that URL?

Let's say that the user is in the URL https://example.com/my-profile and they "Add to Home Screen". Do they can open the PWA and get to that URL or they will be always opening https://example.com only?

Is there a limitation on PWAs or something that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a PWA from a specific URL.

Under your URL at

https://example.com/my-profile

your **my-profile** folder would contain the **index.html** file, the **manifest.json** file and the service worker file. None of that would stop you having a second PWA at

https://example.com/my-profile-2

with it's own set of files. The user could install this as a second app on their device.